# Clang Tidy config format

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

At the moment I am using the Clang Format utility in my project. In order to share its settings in my team, I put the .clang-format configuration file in the root of the project folder, and now IDE automatically loads it when working with the project.
In the same way, I want to use the Clang Tidy utility. However, unlike Clang Format, I cannot find a description of the configuration file format or a utility to create it. I need IDE to also automatically load these settings and take them into account in autoformatting, so it's not possible for me to run the utility using a script that will pass it the necessary parameters. Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: I have got lost in the second part of the question, but you can generate config file with `clang-tidy --dump-config` call. Redirect/save it into `.clang-tidy` file in root of project. See https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/

Comment: I have a lot of custom parameters (for example - codestyle rules for "readability" section) and i didn't want to pass it all into commandline. But if it can create dump config, it will be okay to do this just one time. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.clang-tidy` file format is actually specified in the command-line help, see [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#id2).

```
--config=<string>              -
                                   Specifies a configuration in YAML/JSON format:
                                     -config="{Checks: '*',
                                               CheckOptions: [{key: x,
                                                               value: y}]}"
                                   When the value is empty, clang-tidy will
                                   attempt to find a file named .clang-tidy for
                                   each source file in its parent directories.
  --config-file=<string>         -
                                  Specify the path of .clang-tidy or custom config file:
                                    e.g. --config-file=/some/path/myTidyConfigFile
                                  This option internally works exactly the same way as
                                    --config option after reading specified config file.
                                  Use either --config-file or --config, not both.
```

All you need to do is to put the config string in a file and you're good to go. If you don't specify the `--config-file` option it will automatically search for a `.clang-tidy` file in the directory where the checked code is.

An example `.clang-tidy` file:

```
Checks: '-*,bugprone-*'
CheckOptions:
    - key: bugprone-argument-comment.StrictMode
      value: 1
    - key: bugprone-exception-escape.FunctionsThatShouldNotThrow
      value: WinMain,SDL_main
FormatStyle: 'file'
```

This would run all bugprone checks and set options for two of them.