# How can I silence all errors of a particular kind in clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I'm currently working on a university assignment where it is mandated that we use C-style arrays for our code. Infuriatingly, they have left the default setting for warning about C-style arrays, which means that every time I use a one I need to add a `// NOLINTNEXTLINE(modernize-avoid-c-arrays)`, which is absolutely terrible in terms of readability.

I have tried silencing the errors using `// NOLINTBEGIN(modernize-avoid-c-arrays)`, but since that was only introduced in `clang-tidy-14`, it isn't supported by our course-mandated `clang-tidy-11`.

As such, my only option for a clean way of silencing these errors is by modifying the configuration file. Unfortunately, I haven't found any information on how to silence errors of a particular type in the configuration file. In fact, I haven't found any documentation on the expected structure of the `.clang-tidy` file at all, except for some example files, none of which appear to silence any errors.

How can I silence the `modernize-avoid-c-arrays` error on a project-wide basis from my `.clang-tidy` file?

Comment: Honestly, I think you should talk to your TA about this. Clearly this is an organizational issue. If they mandate you use clang-tidy-11, but also mandate a conflicting coding style, then *that's* the issue to be addressed.

Comment: If you use fixed size arrays you could also ask if it is okay to use std::array, you can do all the same things as with a "C" style array. Or is it a datastructures course where you also have to do things like double pointers, new and delete? Anyway I'm biased since I think courses that use C++ should also teach proper C++ techniques. If I could I would have a chat with your teacher about it)

Comment: @datenwolf Well said :)

Comment: @datenwolf I wish they would care about what students think. Their setup script entirely broke my VS Code config across all of my machines, and installed a ton of programs, some of which broke my updating system, and they were just like "sorry about that I guess"

Comment: @PepijnKramer agreed that would be a good idea, but they've explicitly said we can't sadly.

Comment: The problem that I have with that is that most students will first get to see the "C" style approach and never learn the techniques that will be less buggy.  To bad I can't help you with clang-tidy (only use it very sparingly). As for breaking your own environment consider running theirs in a virtual machine. (Ideally they should proved a docker image or a VM on a network).

Comment: @PepijnKramer technically they do give a VM on a network that we access through VNC, but due to latency I find it an absolute pain to work with, except for doing the final testing before I submit (since it's 32-bit and never seems to compile on the first go, even if it works on my machine). If they gave a docker image, I'd definitely be using that instead, but sadly the one they provided doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Well good luck on your C++ journey, I think you at least have the right mindset :) 
Can you ask your teacher if he is aware of this? https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge: Other than using a VM, my recommendation would be on the machines you own to create a separate user just for university work. Not just for assignments, but also for web browsing, and such; also email if you've got a separate email for uni. Keeps everything related to uni in a single place and doesn't get intertwined with your personal stuff. Also makes it easier to stay focused, by blocking time sinks (social media, games, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disable a check

To disable a check in `.clang-tidy`, add a `Checks:` line, and as its
value put the name of the check, preceded by a hyphen (meaning to
disable rather than enable).  For example, here is a complete
`.clang-tidy` file that first enables all of the `modernize-*` checks
(since they are not enabled by default), then disables
`modernize-avoid-c-arrays`:

```
Checks: 'modernize-*,-modernize-avoid-c-arrays'
```

### Documentation of .clang-tidy format

The `.clang-tidy` format is (tersely!) specified in the
[output of `clang-tidy --help`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/):

```
  --config-file=<string>         -
                                  Specify the path of .clang-tidy or custom config file:
                                    e.g. --config-file=/some/path/myTidyConfigFile
                                  This option internally works exactly the same way as
                                    --config option after reading specified config file.
                                  Use either --config-file or --config, not both.
```

However, the `--config-file` option and its documentation are missing
in Clang+LLVM-11, so that may be why you didn't find it.  They are in
Clang+LLVM-14 (I'm not sure which version introduced that option).
Nevertheless, Clang+LLVM-11 responds to the presence of `.clang-tidy`.

You can use the `--dump-config` option to have `clang-tidy` print its
current configuration in the `.clang-tidy` syntax, then trim or edit as
desired.

Related:

- github gist: [A general clang-tidy configuration file](https://gist.github.com/fbaeuerlein/2895f889e451a817d7b2b36fd60e2873)
- SO question: [Clang Tidy config format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081393/clang-tidy-config-format)

### Complete example

Input source code:

```
// test.cpp
// Test input for clang-tidy.

void f()
{
  int arr[3];
  bool b = 1;
}

// EOF
```

Run using the above `.clang-tidy`:

```
$ /home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-11.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/bin/clang-tidy test.cpp --
1 warning generated.
/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/clang-tidy-config/test.cpp:7:12: warning: converting integer literal to bool, use bool literal instead [modernize-use-bool-literals]
  bool b = 1;
           ^
           true
```

Without disabling `modernize-avoid-c-arrays`, two warnings would be
printed.  (And without enabling `modernize-*`, nothing is printed.)